# How to select table value with where condition in pandas and create csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a csv file from a snowflake table with path stored in table, I also need to add a datetime at the end.

Here is my code:

```
HA = '''SELECT * FROM {}.{}.TABLE'''.format(sf_database,sf_schema)
HA_output = cs.execute(HA)
HA_file_path = ''' select CONFIG_VALUE from {sf_database}.{sf_schema}.CONFIGURATIONS where CONFIG_NAME = 'HA''''  # -- I am getting syntax error here (CONFIG_VALUE store the path of the file )

#+"/HA"+datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d') -- I need to attach file name with current date time in path

HA_output.fetch_pandas_all().to_csv(HA_file_path,index=False,date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

If you could please help me!